# Uboot Option to print boot time prefixes

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader, u-boot

Is there any uboot config option to print boot sequence with time prefixes similar to kernel option CONFIG_PRINTK?

I am expecting output like below,

```
[    0.000000] U-Boot 1.1.4-gedeced79 (Feb  6 2012 - 09:27:11)
[    0.011300] Starting kernel ...
[    0.015686] Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel
```

Answer (score 2):

define DEBUG config option is best for your purpose, it is picked up by all u-boot code after you put it in your include/configs/myboard.h. (each config option is '#define', but that is doing strange things in my page preview)

Also 
define CONFIG_BOOTSTAGE.
You can look at README for this, code is in common/bootstage.c, its functions do some of what you want. You may have to add a function show_boot_progress() in your BSP, for these functions to be used. With those in place, I believe there are already hooks in infrastructure code for them to get called, but I haven't used this option.

Comment: Per README (2012.10 line 2356):
#define CONFIG_SHOW_BOOT_PROGRESS #define CONFIG_BOOTSTAGE #define CONFIG_BOOTSTAGE_REPORT

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of U-Boot config option that does such thing, but there are some other techniques which enables you to do it. I.e. config option inside the Linux kernel.

Take a look at: [Measuring Boot-up time](http://elinux.org/Boot_Time#Measuring_Boot-up_Time)

Comment: Could you explain how config options in the kernel would generate output from U-Boot?

Comment: I understood that you want to print the time whilst booting the linux-kernel (there's a linux-kernel tag in a question). There is no integrated functionality to do such thing in the U-Boot. But however, on the given link, there are some techniques that could be reused (i.e. grabserial). Another unlikely option would be to integrate such functionality by yourself into the U-Boot source code.

Comment: The questions sure seems to be about adding / enabling such functionality in the uboot source code.